# Finding IMethod from IType by method name

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

Let's say I have Hello class that has hello method.

```
public class Hello {
public int hello(int x, int y)
```

I need to get the IMethod reference of "hello" method. 
This is the code that I could get IType (Hello).

```
IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
// 1. The name of the project in the workspace
IProject project = root.getProject("Hello");
project.open(null /* IProgressMonitor */);

IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);
// 2. The name of the Type (including the namespace)
IType itype = javaProject.findType("smcho.HelloRenameMethod");

IMethod method = itype.findMethod() // ???
```

I googled IType#findMethod(), but [the input parameter for this method is an IMethod instance, not a string](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IType.html).

How can I get IMethod from IType with the method name? Or, how can I use the `IType#findMethod()` to get IMethod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use `getMethod` to get IMethod with method name.

```
IMethod method = itype.getMethod("hello", new String[] {"I", "I"});
```

Comment: I tried this `itype.getMethod(string, string[])` method too, and it return the target method. But the status of target method is `(not open)`. Do you have this issue? Thanks.